# Android Motion Event

Tags: android, motionevent

I am trying the android motion event. However, I do not know why it cant go to > case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

Here is my codes.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            startX = (int)event.getX();
            startY = (int)event.getY();
            selecting=false;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            selecting=true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(selecting){
                endX = (int)event.getX();
                endY = (int)event.getY();
                selected=true;
            }
            selecting=false;
            break;

    }
}
```

No matter how I swipe and touch, even if I remove if(selecting) condition in case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, it always show same output.

> start: {498.0, 365.0}
>   end: {0.0, 0.0}
>   selecting: false
>   selected: false

After I change it to

> public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)

everything is okay. Can anyone explain to me why does it happen?

If possible, help me to solve this problem too. [How to get the actual point when I touch on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988449/how-to-get-the-actual-point-when-i-touch-on-screen)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the following MotionEvents, you must return `true` in the `onTouchEvent` method.

[source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))